# .NET Controller Class runs first method for GET

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I don't know the best way to ask this, but here goes. Why is it when I call my API, if I don't specify a name it runs the first method? Is there a way to specify a default method, or disable that functionality?

I have a .NET Core WebAPI project, and in my controller, I ended up adding a helper method to my class.

```
public async Task<String> verify() {
 return "Gotcha";
}

HttpGet("GetIceCreamFlavors")
public async Task<FlavorList> GetIceCreamFlavors() {
 ...Calls verify()... 
}
```

If I run this with:
GET URL/api/IceCream/GetIceCreamFlavors, it works. However, GET URL/api/IceCream, runs the verify method instead, even though there are no methods annotated with just [HttpGet] in the class.

I would have expected it to return a 404.

I patched it by adding a method to the top:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult nop()
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
```

But my approach must be wrong. What did I do wrong here, is there a way just to say "If the route is not found, return 404, don't just run the first method"

Comment: Modify your `Verify` method to `private`. By default all the `public` method in the Controller will be applied with `HttpGet` attribute.

Comment: Is adding HttpGet with no name to it, the reason it's defaulting if I give it something undefined, like /api/Home/wuoindwiehdilwhd" it's running it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expected it to return a 404` when the URL is wrong there will be a 404 error.

And just like Yong said above, public method will be attached `[HttpGet]`. So the URL is correct and no-404-error is the expected behavior. By the way, if you have 2 methods in the same Controller which one of it missing `[HttpGet]` it will cause that missing method can't be reached.

[image]
[image]

So in my humble opinion, the best option for you is setting detailed route value for each `Get` request, and leave only one `Get` method which is used to return the default value you want such as "404 error" with general `[HttpGet]` attribute.

Or you may change the Controller to implement `Controller` instead of `ControllerBase`, just like the MVC project, and then setting the default route as `/home/index/id?`, in this scenario, when you don't have an `index` action method in your Controller but you call `localhost:port/home`, it will give you 404 error.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I need to clarify that in your example you are calling /verify directly - whereas instead I'm doing "/api/Home/GetIceCreamFlavors" and it's going straight to the correct, but if I put anything else "/api/Home/shfdo9whwhd" it's going to /verify for some reason. Does a straight [HttpGet] just end up being a catch-all anyway then?

Comment: `/api/Home/GetIceCreamFlavors` is the route defined in the api project because there's no route mapping in webapi project's `Program.cs`. But in a MVC project, there will be a route mapping, so I can only define a `/verify` route in the Controller. Anyway, in a `ControllerBase` Controller, when no `HttpGet` appeared in the Controller, the first method without Get or Post definition will be recognized as a HttpGet method. If there's already a HttpGet method, the other method without HttpGet attribution will not be able to access.